# UITableViewCell Custom Swipe View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, gesture

I would like to design my own UITableViewCell Swipe View.
Is it possible to apply your own view on a cell instead of ulitizing the standard delete button?

I'm not looking for custom buttons, but a custom view with a label and a button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, probably this tutorial can help you out: http://www.appcoda.com/swipeable-uitableviewcell-tutorial/

Comment: I've tried SWTableViewCell, but as far as I could see, it was designed for use with buttons only.